# Venn diagram notation for all other sets except one

Tags: dataset, venn-diagram, venn

I'm trying to find a Venn diagram notation that can illustrate data that is only in a single set.

If I can select data from all the other sets, without knowing how many there are, then I can find the intersection of their complement, to select data only in the targeting set.

My current solution looks like this, but it assumes the existance of sets B and C.

[image]

The eventual diagram expecting to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be by using a system based on regions rather than sets. In your case, it would be the region that belongs to set `A` but does not belong to any other set. You can find the rationale to do that [here](http://degradome.uniovi.es/vqf/SCD.html). The idea is to express the region as a binary chain where `1` means "belongs to set n" and `0` means "does not belong to set n", where `n` is determined by the ordering of the sets.

In your example, you might define `A` as the last set, and therefore as the last bit. With three sets `CBA`, your region would be `001`. The nice thing about this is that the leading zeroes can be naturally disregarded. Your region would be `1b`, not matter how many sets there are (the `b` is for "binary").

You might even extend the idea by translating the number to another base. For instance, say that you want to express the region of elements belonging to set `B` only. With the same ordering as before, it would be `010` or `10b`. But you can also express it as a decimal number and say "region 2". This expression would be valid if sets `A` and `B` exist, independently of the presence of any other set.